# addDataPoints on here maps is not working

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I've been trying to dynamically add data points to a **HERE map** using the `addDataPoints()` and the `addDataPoint()` methods (and I still don't get why would you need two different methods...).

When I try to use them I get this error:

```
Error: this.tb.push is not a function
m.Jb@https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js line 47 > eval:2:734
m.Fi@https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js line 47 > eval:24:52
W.prototype.Fi@https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js line 47 > eval:27:209
self.populateCluster@http://localhost:3000/scripts/panel/controller.js:208:3
```

`populateCluster()` is the function who calls `addDataPoints()`, defined as follow:

```
        clusterProvider = new H.clustering.Provider({});

        var poisFormattedAsDataPoint = poiManager.pois[category].map( function( poi ){

            var tmpPoi = new H.clustering.DataPoint( poi.position[0], poi.position[1], null, poi );
            return tmpPoi;

        });

        clusterProvider.addDataPoints( poisFormattedAsDataPoint );

        var clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer( clusterProvider );

        map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);
```

If I add the same array of `DataPoints` in the Provider definition everything works fine (which I believe proves that the data I'm using is well formatted), but since I have to add the points dynamically this is not an option.

Does anyone have a working example of these two functions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the error. 
I'm initializing the Provider with an empty object, and should be initialized with an empty array. So

`clusterProvider = new H.clustering.Provider({});`

should be

`clusterProvider = new H.clustering.Provider([]);`

Question is, should it be allowed to initialize the provider with the wrong set of data? or should it return an error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not allowing me to initialize cluster provider like without clusteringOptions, but when I provided clusteringOptions is worked :

```
clusterProvider = new H.clustering.Provider([], {
      clusteringOptions: {
        eps: 32,
        minWeight: 2
      }
    });
```